# How to search for multiple string in s single gzip file?

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I am trying to open a zip file and search for a specific string. Here, if 'result =one ' then I should search for another specific string called 'next' in the same file but in different lines and print line that contains 'next'.

example:

```
next line
result = one
asdfgh
...
waiting for next line
please wait to print the next line
```

So first it should search for 'result = one' and then it should search for 'next' in a  file.
Expected output :

```
next line
waiting for next line
please wait to print the next line
```

work I am trying

```
     with gzip.open ('result.gz', 'rt') as i:
         for line in i:
             if 'result = one' in line:
                 continue
                 if 'next' in line:
                     print (line)
```

When I am searching for 'result = one' I can find it and when I am trying to search for the 'next' string it is not giving me any output. It is giving the exact line that I need only when I am doing it alone. Any help in solving this would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Don't worry about gzip. It just confuses the issue. A normal file or even a list is much easier to work with to develop the algorithm

Comment: `continue` skips your `if 'next' in line` and go to the next iteration in the for loop. It is not clear what you mean with once you find 'result = one` then search for another specific string called 'next in the same file. Could you give an input example and expected output?

Comment: @Anton updated the question. I hope it is  clear

Comment: @AnaS See my answer. I suggest you learn the basic loop first: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Comment: @AnaS Don't forget to mark your question answered if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as searching for an arbitrary string in some order. You start with `'result = one'`. If that's found, you keep doing the same thing, but for `'next'`.

You can actually make the algorithm work for a general sequence, where the last element is printed when it's found.

```
keys = ['result = one', 'next']
search = enumerate(keys, start=1)

i, key = next(search)
for line in file:
    if key in line:
        if i == len(keys):
            print(line)
            break
        else:
            i, key = next(search)
else:
    print('Not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you use `continue` in your for loop. `continue` basically ends the current iteration, so it won't execute your `if 'next' in line:`.

After your updated text, it is still not very clear, but this code might do what you want.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import gzip

with gzip.open('result.gz', 'rt') as i:
    find_next = False
    for line in i:
        if not find_next and 'result = one' in line:
            find_next = True
        elif find_next and 'next' in line:
            print(line.strip())
```

I use a flag called `find_next`. It starts with a `False`. It is set to `True` after it finds `result = one`. Basically, it changes the state to find the word `next` until the end of the file. You can adjust the code as you wanted.

**Edited the solution**:
OP wrote in the description that 'next' can be found in the same file, but from the comment on my answer, 'next' is expected in the same line:
I would use a regex here which is easier:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import gzip
import re

# Find 'result = one' then any characters followed by 'next' till the end of the line.
PATTERN = re.compile("(result = one).+(next).*")

with gzip.open('result.gz', 'rt') as i:
    for line in i:
        if PATTERN.search(line):
            print(line.strip())
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and I am not sure whether you are trying to search for both 'result= one' and 'next' in the same line or no. Because, eli seems like you are searching for both the words in a single line. If that is the case you mentioned above, They will not be in a single line. Unfortunately, I couldn't see anything in the output section.

Comment: Where is in your input example that contains 'next' in the same line? In your description, you didn't mention it: `search for another specific string called 'next' in the same file`. Could you update your INPUT correctly with the expected OUTPUT?

Comment: @AnaS See the updated answer with finding 'result = one' and 'next' in the same line. I use regex though, which is easier.